# I have a Data Type as a Multi Line of Text to convert to choice

Tags: powerapps

I would like to try and give choices for a column that is multi line of text by default (I can't change this setting as it was imported as multi line).

Is there a way to add choice to Power App when the data type can't be edited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe with this approach:

In your Power Apps canvas app you likely have a Rich Text Editor control to give value for your Multiline Text field.

Above the control add Buttons or Labels with the Option Texts. These have an OnSelect property, here input this formula: `Set(strRTEDefault,Self.Text)`

Set the Rich Text Editor control's Default property to strRTEDefault.

Optional:

Set the Multiline Text field to DisplayMode.Disabled if you want that users can only use options but no free text.

Set an initial value in the screen's OnVisible property using the same `Set(strRTEDefault,"Most likely choice")`